# jQuery option value set of select element not working for encrypted values

Tags: jquery

I want to make my select box selected with an encrypted value.

I have a select box with id gallery_category. I have a variable with encrypted value and i
tried  to this code which is not working for encrypted value but works fine for integer value.

My Code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="gallery_category" name="gallery_category" tcid="ZGNjZQL9ac3K">
    <option value="">Select subcategory</option>
    <option value="ZGNjZGR9ac3K">Nostalgia</option>
    <option value="ZGNjAQV9ac3K">College FlashBack</option>
</select>
var tpSubCategoryActive = '<?=$miscObj->encode_4a($activeSubCatId,ENC_TYPE)?>';
// the encrypted value will be like ZGNjZGR9ac3K 
    if(tpSubCategoryActive){
            jQuery('#gallery_category').val(tpSubCategoryActive);
        }
```

Comment: @AshleyMedway But it is truthly value

Comment: @AShley: but it is a string, and strings are truthy; so it should evaluate to `true`.

Comment: What is your issue? `IF` condition not pass or what?

Comment: i just want to make this select box selected with this encrypted value as all my options are having encrypted value.

Comment: @Wolf yes its coming inside IF condition...

Comment: So provide relevant HTML markup for SELECT element. Any option with relevant value?

Comment: As you see, it works, so your issue comes from somewhere we aren't aware of: http://jsfiddle.net/5utxg3f5/  Maybe try just to trim `tpSubCategoryActive `

Comment: @All updated the SELECT Markup... yes the value i am trying to set and available option value is same... when i tried to add single quotes around the encrypted value from console it got selected correctly

Comment: @Wolf yes indeed its works when we hard-code the encrypted value... but don't know why this is not working when the value is set from php....

Comment: when i console "console.log(jQuery('#gallery_category').val(jQuery.trim(tpSubCategoryActive)))" i get like this in console:: [context: document, selector: "#gallery_category", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]